# Word Labels for Document Matrix in Gensim

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, gensim

My ultimate goal is to produce a *.csv file containing **labeled** binary term vectors for each document. In essence, a term document matrix.

Using gensim, I can produce a file with an unlabeled term matrix.

I do this by essentially copying and pasting code from here: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html

Given a list of documents called "texts".

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
print(corpus)
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)]
[(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
[(1, 1), (5, 2), (8, 1)]
[(3, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)]
[(9, 1)]
[(9, 1), (10, 1)]
[(9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)]
[(4, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)]
```

To convert the above vectors into a numpy matrix, I use:

```
scipy_csc_matrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(corpus)
```

I then convert the sparse numpy matrix to a full array:

```
full_matrix = csc_matrix(scipy_csc_matrix).toarray()
```

Finally, I output this to a file:

```
with open('file.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(full_matrix)
```

This produces a matrix of binomial vectors, but I do not know which vector represents which word. Is there an accurate way of matching words to vectors?

I've tried parsing the dictionary to creative a list of words which I would glue to the above full_matrix.

```
#Retrive dictionary
tokenIDs = dictionary.token2id

#Retrieve keys from dictionary and concotanate those to full_matrix
for key, value in tokenIDs.iteritems():
    temp1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', key).encode('ascii','ignore')
    temp = [temp1]
    dictlist.append(temp)

Keys = np.asarray(dictlist)

#Combine Keys and Matrix
labeled_full_matrix = np.concatenate((Keys, full_matrix), axis=1)
```

However, this does not work. The word ids (Keys) are not matched to the appropriate vectors.

I am under the assumption a much simpler and more elegant approach is possible. But after some time, I haven't been able to find it. Maybe someone here can help, or point me to something fundamental I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
%time lda1 = models.LdaModel(corpus1, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary1, update_every=5, chunksize=10000, passes=100)

import pandas

mixture = [dict(lda1[x]) for x in corpus1]

pandas.DataFrame(mixture).to_csv("output.csv")
```